# reduce sum of digits recursivel down to a one digit number

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to solve a challenge (Digit Degree) on Code signal where the task is to find the the number of times we need to replace this number with the sum of its digits until we get to a one digit number. I.e. of the incoming number is 5 it's already a one digit number so the outcome should be 0. If the number is 100 the sum of its digits is 1 which is one digit so the outcome should be 1 and so on...

I'm doing a recursive solution like this:

```
let count = 0;
function digitDegree(n) {
  if (n < 10) {
    console.log(count);
    return count;
  };
  const arr = n.toString().split('').map(Number);
  const sumOfDigits = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr);
  count++;
  digitDegree(sumOfDigits);
}
```

At the second loop and forth I'm getting null as output even if the console log shows the correct value. Where does it go wrong?

I saw that the question was up before but the answer was quite mathematical. Would this approach be ok or would it be considered bad practise?

Comment: you do not need of return count as it as a global scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return a value, update the last line in your function to `return digitDegree(sumOfDigits)`

```js
function digitDegree(n) {
  if (n < 10) {
    console.log(count);
    return count;
  };
  const arr = n.toString().split('').map(Number);
  const sumOfDigits = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr);
  count++;
  // add return 
  return digitDegree(sumOfDigits);
}
```

---

### Pitfalls with your current approach:

**It's impure.**

`digitDegree(100)` returns 1 the first time you run it but returns 2 when you run it again. This is because `count` was declared outside the function (making it global)

```js
let count = 0
function digitDegree(n) {
  if (n < 10) {
    return count;
  };
  const arr = n.toString().split('').map(Number);
  const sumOfDigits = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr);
  count++;
  return digitDegree(sumOfDigits);
}
// wrong - output should not change
console.log(digitDegree(100))  //=> 1
console.log(digitDegree(100))  //=> 2
console.log(digitDegree(100))  //=> 3
```

### Make your function pure

> A **pure function** is a specific kind of value-producing function that not only has no side effects but also doesn’t rely on side effects from other code—for example, **it doesn’t read global bindings whose value might change.**
>
> A pure function has the pleasant property that, when called with the same arguments, it always produces the same value (and doesn’t do anything else)
>   [Source](https://eloquentjavascript.net/03_functions.html)

Suggestions:

1. Pass `count` as an argument

```js
function digitDegree(n,count=0) {
  if (n < 10) {
    return count;
  };
  const arr = n.toString().split('').map(Number);
  const sumOfDigits = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr);
  count++;
  return digitDegree(sumOfDigits, count);
}
// correct
console.log(digitDegree(100)) //=> 1
console.log(digitDegree(100)) //=> 1
console.log(digitDegree(100)) //=> 1
```

2. Wrap your recursion function inside another function

```js
function recursionWrapper(num){
  let count = 0;
  function digitDegree(n) {
    if (n < 10) {
      return count;
    };
    const arr = n.toString().split('').map(Number);
    const sumOfDigits = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr);
    count++;
    // notice how we don't need a return in this approach
    digitDegree(sumOfDigits)
  }
  digitDegree(num)
  return count
}
// correct
console.log(recursionWrapper(100))  //=> 1
console.log(recursionWrapper(100))  //=> 1
console.log(recursionWrapper(100))  //=> 1
```

Further reading:

- [How to deal with dirty side effects in your pure functional JavaScript](https://jrsinclair.com/articles/2018/how-to-deal-with-dirty-side-effects-in-your-pure-functional-javascript/)
- [Javascript and Functional Programming — Pt. 3: Pure Functions](https://hackernoon.com/javascript-and-functional-programming-pt-3-pure-functions-d572bb52e21c)

Answer (score 2):

You need a [`return` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) for getting the result of the recursion.

```
return digitDegree(sumOfDigits);
```

A shorter approach would remove explicit conversions in advance and remove temporary arrays.

Then take another parameter for count and omit a global variable.

```js
function digitDegree(n, count = 0) {
    if (n < 10) return count;
  
    return digitDegree(
        n   .toString()
            .split('')
            .reduce((acc, curr) => acc + +curr, 0),
        count + 1
    );
}

console.log(digitDegree(9999));
```